# Column ( ) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined). SQLCODE=-217

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, db2

I am reading a table from like this:

```
query = (
"select mandant,posnr,systemdat,
"lieferbedingung,loeschhafen,bereich," 
"nrkreis_nr from eakopf_t where posnr[10,10] = \" \" and posnr[1,2] not in (\"99\",\"RE\",\"UB\") and mandant <> 999;"
)

df = pd.read_sql(query, engine.connect())
```

But I get this error:

```
ibm_db_dbi::DatabaseError: SQLNumResultCols failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][IDS/UNIX64] Column ( ) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined). SQLCODE=-217
[SQL: select mandant,posnr,systemdat,lieferbedingung,loeschhafen,bereich,nrkreis_nr from eakopf_t where posnr[10,10] = " " and posnr[1,2] not in ("99","RE","UB") and mandant <> 999;]
```

Is it possible to further debug which is the exact col that's causing an issue? Because otherwise, all col names seem to exist in the dataset.

Comment: It is annoying that you aren’t given the column name; that should appear in the parentheses.  It would appear that you have misspelled some column name.  You aren’t using any SLV (statement local variable).

Comment: One possibility is that you are running with `DELIMIDENT` set in your environment, in which case the `” “` would be interpreted as a column name consisting of a single blank.  Although there are other double-quoted strings, the single blank is the first and so will be the one reported.  Try using embedded single quotes around the strings.

Comment: Should that be tagged informix instead of db2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of a guess because I can't see your database, but this line:

```
posnr[10,10] = " "
```

is suspect to me. At least in Postgres, double quotes indicate column names, which would give you an error like this. I would suggest replacing any double quotes intended to represent strings with single quotes and try again. ie)

```
posnr[10,10] = ' '
```

Comment: Informix allows single quotes or double quotes around strings unless the `DELIMIDENT` environment variable is set.  Your advice to use single quotes is sensible, but using double quotes is (probably) not the cause of the trouble this time.